# Calling a variable in a separate method/function inside a class in a PyQt script

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, methods

I have a script like this

```
class CreateSomething(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(CreateSomething, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Activates the functions when the plugin is first opened
        self.getLayerInfo()
        self.anotherMethod()
        # Emits a signal and activates the function when the 
        # selected layer is changed
        self.cmbLyrSelect.layerChanged.connect(self.getLayerInfo) 
        # Same as above but when the field is changed
        self.cmbLyrFields.fieldChanged.connect(self.getLayerInfo)

    def getLayerInfo(self):
        # Stores the current layer, a QgsVectorLayer, in a variable
        currLyr = self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer()
        ...
    
    def anotherMethod(self):
        # Prints the layer name of the currently selected layer which is
        # stored in the currLyr variable in the previous method
        self.lineEdit.setText(currLyr.sourceName())
```

I've tried multiple changing currLyr to `self.currLyr = self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer()` and the last line to `self.linTranslate.setText(self.currLyr.sourceName())` but both Python and QGIS return an error saying `"currLyr" is not defined`.

For context, the following script works but I want to separate create a method for each different task.

```
def getLayerInfo(self):
    currLyr = self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer()
    self.lineEdit.setText(currLyr.sourceName())
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks to the first example in this article
https://www.geekpills.com/operating-system/linux/python-passing-variable-between-functions

The following script now works as intended

```
class CreateSomething(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(CreateSomething, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.getLayerInfo()
        self.anotherMethod() 
        self.cmbLyrSelect.layerChanged.connect(self.getLayerInfo) 
        self.cmbLyrFields.fieldChanged.connect(self.getLayerInfo)

    def getLayerInfo(self):
        currLyr = self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer()
        return currLyr # ADDED
        ...
    
    def anotherMethod(self):
        currLyr = self.getLayerInfo() # ADDED
        self.lineEdit.setText(currLyr.sourceName())
```